# Can I edit the "Open with..." menu in Apple Mail / Finder?

Tags: finder, mail.app, shortcut-menu

I am aware of ways to remove duplicate entries from the Finder "*Open with...*" menu. But in this instance I simply want to cull down the list of apps that appear when I do "*Open with...*" on pictures. Right now, in Mail (although it's the same in Finder, of course), when I do *Open With* on .jpg files, I get a LONG list of apps, many of which I would never consider opening a picture in. Even a music editing app, that has nothing to do with jpg files (in my opinion) shows up.

Is there a way to edit this list? To cull it down to the essentials? Having to look through 44 applications (in my case) just to find the app I'd like to open a picture with is inefficient and tedious. Please tell me Apple were kind enough to make a way to decide which apps I want to see in that list... :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove entries from the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` dictionaries in `Info.plist` files, but it is not very practical.

For example DVD Player won't be listed as a supported application for `.dvdmedia` files if you:

1. Run `sudo nano /Applications/DVD\ Player.app/Contents/Info.plist` and remove the entry for `dvdmedia`.
2. Run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -f /Applications/DVD\ Player.app/`.
3. Quit and relaunch Finder.

Sandboxed applications like TextEdit and Chess have crashed on launch since 10.8 if their `Info.plist` has been modified. Changes to `Info.plist` files might also get reverted by updates.